# I deleted the home page in my Oracle application express how can i recover it?

Tags: oracle

I'm still a newbie in this so I still don't know how things work. 
Will it affect anything if i made a new page called home?
or can I recover it?

Answer (score 1):

No problem in creating a new page.

Alternatively (though, now is probably too late), you can

- export the application **as of "n" minutes ago** (if you deleted it right now, "n" could be 5 minutes, for example)
- drop the application
- import it back

and you'd have the lost page again.

Answer (score -1):

Can you explain your problem a bit further?

I can recommend to read trough the links below.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/core.1012/b13995/br_intro.htm
https://apexplained.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/recover-a-deleted-apex-page-or-application/